# Dynamically allocated objects in static map. Delete necessary?

Tags: c++

Consider the following contrived example:

```
class AllocatedClass {
public:
   AllocatedClass() : dummy(0) {}
private:
  int dummy;
};

class AllocatingClass {
public:
     AllocatingClass() : list() {}
     ~AllocatingClass() {
        // CANNOT delete the elements in list here because there may
        // be more than on instance of AllocatingClass sharing the same
        // static list 
     }
     AddNewObject() {
        list.push_back(new AllocatedClass());
     }
private:
     static std::vector<AllocatedClass*> list;

};
```

In implemetation file

```
std::vector<AllocatedClass*> AllocatingClass::list;
```

---

Putting aside whether multiple instances of a class should share a list of dynamically allocated objects is a good idea, is there a way clean up these new'ed AllocatedClass objects at the end of the program?  Does it matter if these never get deleted considering I don't want to delete them until application end?

Comment: What about using [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) ?

Comment: Every `new()` needs to see it's corresponding `delete`.

Comment: This code is simply not compialable. VTC.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, that is not always true. There are valid cases when `new` is not followed by `delete`.

Comment: Definitely use a std::shared_ptr without a static list.  If they can share them and you need to make sure they get deleted, reference counting is probably your only sane way, and shared_ptr will do that for you.  If you don't want to delete them until application end, you can just let them get cleaned up by the OS if you are certain it won't be a memory leak, but that's generally a Bad Idea, because of course that's inviting memory leaks and guaranteeing that side-effects of the destructor won't happen.

Comment: Where you really get screwed over on the let the OS deal situation, assuming you've done your homework and there are no unfortunate side effects, is when someone comes along and says, "Let's adapt this known working system and include it as a module in Project Y." Boy is that dev team in for a nasty surprise.

Answer (score 2):

If the lifetime of the object is the lifetime of the execution of the program then there is no need to free the memory with code. The memory will be free automatically.

Many Linux command line tools do not free their memory in code for performance reasons. (Faster to automatically free pages of memory, than to free each object one by one.)

Another strategy is to keep a separate list of unique AllocatedClass instances, then free them from that list later on (switching ownership of the objects). Like `std::list<AllocatedClass*> to_be_freed`.

Comment: Destructors can have side-effects, and deleting isn't always just about freeing memory.

Comment: Neverthless, programs which take time to shut down are very annoying. So if you can safely eliminate the deallocation step at the end of your program, and it's beneficial in reducing the execution duration of your program, then go for it. Just make sure you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way clean up these new'ed AllocatedClass objects at the end
>   of the program?

One solution is to use [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and have the deallocation done automatically.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class AllocatedClass 
{
    public:
       AllocatedClass(int n = 0) : dummy(n) {}
       ~AllocatedClass() { std::cout << "I am being destroyed" << '\n'; }
    private:
       int dummy;
};

class AllocatingClass 
{
    public:
         AllocatingClass() {}
         void AddNewObject(int num = 0) 
         {  shared_list.push_back(std::make_shared<AllocatedClass>(num)); }
    private:
         static std::vector<std::shared_ptr<AllocatedClass>> shared_list;
};

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<AllocatedClass>> AllocatingClass::shared_list;

AllocatingClass ac;

int main()
{
    ac.AddNewObject();
    ac.AddNewObject(1);
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/RjKWyM)

Note that the destructors are called automatically for the objects that were placed in the vector.

(BTW, it isn't a good idea to name your member variable `list`).

Comment: LOL at "I am being destroyed". I can picture the `vector`'s comment, "Now I am become Death, the destroyer of worlds." That or maniacal laughter.

Comment: If the object's are not actually being shared around, they only reside inside the `vector`, then `std::unique_ptr` would make more sense than `std::shared_ptr`. Of course, it would make even more sense to change the `vector` from `vector<AllocatedClass*>` to `vector<AllocatedClass>`, and then change `shared_list.push_back(std::make_shared<AllocatedClass>(num));` to `shared_list.push_back(num);`, and let the STL handle the memory for you.

Answer (score -1):

Most of the time(very close to all the time) an object that creates dynamically allocated objects should have a programmer defined destructor to free the memory when the object reaches the end of its life. `AllocatingClass` should have a destructor because you allocate dynamic memory with `new`.

```
~AllocatingClass() {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < list.size();i++) {
        if(list[i] != NULL) {
            delete list[i];
            list[i] = NULL;
        }
}
```

This should both provide a method for de-allocating memory and safety so that you do not delete an already deleted pointer.

Comment: You don't want this; `list` is static and shared, but you are deleting it at the first `~AllocatingClass`. If AllocatingClass is a singleton, it should use some sort of standard implementation thereof.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus in the question it says to ignore the possibility of sharing dynamically allocated lists.

Comment: On my reading, it says not to get into a code war over whether it is acceptable style, not OK to write code that won't work in that set up.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus I added safety to the deletion process for shared dynamically allocated data.

Comment: The new version is still not thread-safe; it has a race condition. Safe multithreaded programming is hard and can't be done with this sort of unlocked code.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus This question didn't mention the possibility of multiple thread execution. You are down-voting me based on problems with the code that aren't mentioned in the question. Please refer to [how to answer a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) when you decide whether to upvote or downvote a question, specifically  the "Answer the Question" section where it states to answer the specific question asked.